# Cross-reference two datasets in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Given two sets of objects, call them apples and oranges.
apples contains an ID and a name.
oranges contains an appleID and an integer.

The apples are mapped to a html table with the name on each row.

Next to the name is a checkbox which is checked when that apples ID exists in the oranges collection.
If the checkbox is checked, a textbox/dropdown bound to the oranges integer shows up as well.

The one thing I really need some help with, is how to get the orange object for each row in the template, and also how to best add and remove oranges as checkboxes are checked/unchecked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could do is map the oranges set to a structure like the following:

```
oranges = {
    'abc': 5,
    'abd': 20
}
```

where 'abc' and 'abd' are appleIds and 5 and 20 are the corresponding integers.

this way you can easily evaluate and access from your ng-repeat over apples if a corresponding orange-entry exists - and if so what the corresponding number is.
in case you want to remove an oranges entry simply set it to undefined or even better delete it with the 'delete' command.

just do something like

```
<div ng-repeat="apple in apples">
    {{ apple.name }} :
    <div ng-if="oranges[apple.id] !== undefined">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-change="onCheckboxChange(oranges[apple.id].number)" ng-model="oranges[apple.id].number" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, I suppose that is a good solution, I still need to work out how to best handle the checkboxes though.. I have bad experiences with click events up through the years, but could I databind a value change somehow to an event hander?

Comment: absolutely, you can use the ng-change directive for this.
furthermore you can bind the value of the checkboxes via ng-model to the oranges values as i supposed.
i will change my answer accordingly to show you what i mean.

Comment: and another tip: if you get problems by defining too many (click-) listeners in an ng-repeat you have the option to define ONE listener on the parent element and evaluate which child was clicked by the $event property.
if you have a list of hundreds or thousands of elements this is actually the correct way to do this although its a bit tricky to implement it right.
unfortunately AngularJS doesn't come up with a better solution while React for example handles this out-of-the-box (it "refactors" your listeners automatically)

Comment: I needed to add this to get it to work; controller.related = { appleid : true }; and set the ng-model of the checkbox to ctrl.related[apple.id]

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're importing/loading apples and oranges from separate sources, but that's no reason to keep them separate, right? Instead of having two objects with one reduntant property, you can simply extend your apples object by adding an oranges integer to it (if it exists).

So instead of:

```
var apples = [{id, name}];
var oranges = [{appleID, int}];
```

simply use (you might need to process the original data first):

```
var apples = [{id, name, int}];
```

Comment: The apples and oranges are part of a bigger whole, shared across multiple contexts, The lists will potentially grow very large over time and I would like to avoid loading them multiple times for each context

Comment: Also, I want to avoid having to synchronize the various lists as changes are made

Comment: Thought so, I'm actually suggesting you load it only once, but process it before use. Although it might seem heavy at first, making angular combine them in each digest will probably be heavier.

Comment: Ah, fair point with the synchronizing, my approach would complicate it then.

Comment: If no smart solution comes along, processing the list for that one view is an acceptable solution, I will mull it over for a bit :)